# The value of a range from another page

Tags: php, html, javascript

I want to have a program with range and at the end I want to give the user all the results.

First of all the range

**Javascript**:

```
 function imgShow(Target)
 {
   for(var i=1; i<=images; i++)
   {
        if(i != Target) 
          document.getElementById('img' + i).style.display = 'none';
        else 
          document.getElementById('img' + i).style.display = 'block';
   }
 }
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="range" id="slider" max="<?php echo ($images*1); ?>" min="1"
   value="1" onchange="imgShow(parseInt(this.value/1));" />
 <output>
  <?php 
    for ($i=0; $i<$images; $i++){
      $image = $files[$i];
      echo '<div id="img' . ($i+1) . '" class="photo" style=""><img src="' . $image . '" /></div>';
    }
  ?>
</output>
```

> ***The code above is GOOD (I just write this so you know which variables I use)***

You see I give the value of the range each time it change an image. Then **my problem**, I need to take the results from above and put them in another page so i can put it in a database. I want to show it in that other page in a textarea so the users know what they have scored on the test.

```
 echo '<form action="'. $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] .'" method="post">';
 echo 'Solution:<br>';
 echo '<textarea name="message"></textarea><br>';
 echo '</form>';
```

I guess I need to write something between textarea but I don't know what. Already tried some things. Yes echo's because I do this in the else of "if($_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD]=='POST')".

I really hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: These type of questions are great on stack overflow. Voted for migration.

Comment: Can a user migrate it or can only a moderator do that?

Comment: Yep no problem at all m8... It's already in the works! You have no need to do anything other than check back later.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

You can direct users to the properer page using the `switch` function: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

When it comes to saving that result to a database, maybe this will help you: [How to pass javascript variables to a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337807/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-a-database)

I would say that when you generate the link to the next page, put the `post` function in that link. Hope that helps.